# Paramiko SSHClient select an option from menu in shell

Tags: paramiko

I'm trying to run some commands on a linux machine using Paramiko.

After one command there is a menu, and I want to type "R" and press Enter.

Here is my code:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )
ssh.connect(hostname, port, username, password)


stdin = ssh.exec_command("")
conn = ssh.invoke_shell()
print("Interactive SSH session established")

output = conn.recv(1000)
conn.send("gohome\n")
conn.send("rollout\n")
conn.send("R")
conn.send("\n")

time.sleep(5)
output = str(conn.recv(10000))
print(output.replace("\\r", "").replace("\\n", "\n")[-500:])
```

This script does not take the "`R`" and "`\n`" in, and exits after "`rollout\n`"

The output shows that the R has not been input.

What can I do here?

Here is the menu after the 'rollout' command:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the command does not have a switch or configuration that allows bypassing the interactive menu?

Comment: Btw, you should remove the `stdin = ssh.exec_command("")`.

Comment: Bypassing the interactive menu...? But I do need and want to select one of the options (R)...

Comment: I guess there are things paramiko can't do :/

Comment: Hardly. It's just matter of sending a correct input to the server. Not a Paramiko limitation.

Comment: Well, do you know what the correct input is?

Comment: We need [mcve]. Give us an example of a command that we can test it against that has the same problem as your script.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem, I changed

```
conn.send("rollout\n")
```

to

```
conn.send("source rollout\n")
```

and that allowed to interact with the menu.

Comment: So the problem was not with `R` at all, but with starting the `rollout` in the first place.